# Use of Raw Notifications in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I read the implementation of three types of notifications possible in WP7 app - Tile, Toast and Raw Notifications. I understand the use of Tile and Toast Notifications but I fail to understand how a Raw notification will be used in real world application. Can someone please help me understand.

If someone can help me understand the implementation wrt. an existing application like KIK messenger or WhatsApp Messenger, it will be great!

Regards,
Bhavik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw notifications provides the ability for your application service to push data to the application while it is in the foreground without the need for your application to poll the appplication service.

For instance, meaning if you have the Messages application open, and you get a new Message, it'll show a notification (toast), without the Messages application having to poll for it.

Comment: But if I understand it correctly, my App needs to be opened to recieve the raw notification. In that case, do i need to make sure something at web service end to send Toast or Raw?

Comment: Toasts only appear when the app is closed (this is annoying) Raw notifications only work when the app is open. The webservice needs to send either or both depending on what you're trying to do

Comment: A limitation of the public API. The restricted partner API allows you toasts on top of the active app as well.

Comment: RAW notifications work when the application is closed as well. See Skype.